# numerical calculations with the items in a list

Tags: python

I am back again with another python query. I have been trying to do some calculations with the items present in a list. Here is the code:

```
import math

def Usage() :
    print "Usage :python beznew.py transcriptionsFile"

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    if len(sys.argv) != 2 : 
        Usage() 

    else :
        transcriptionFile = sys.argv[1]
        tFile = open(transcriptionFile, "r")

        for line in iter(tFile) :
            list = line.split()

            # changing the unit of time from 100 nano seconds to seconds
            list[0] = list[0] / 100000000
            list[1] = list[1] / 100000000

            # duration of each phoneme
            list = list[1] - list[0]

            # extracting the start time of each phoneme
            newlist = list.pop[0]    

            print list
            print newlist

        close.tFile
```

The input file looks like the following:

```
000000 1200000 pau

1200000 1600000 dh

1600000 2000000 ih

2000000 3100000 k

3100000 3400000 aa

3400000 3800000 r
```

I am trying to change the numerical values to seconds. And also trying to get the difference between first and second numbers. It would not allow me to divide. I dont understand what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I m sorry forgot to mention about the error clearly.

Comment: A point concerning the algorithm: when you do ``list = list[1] - list[0]`` , ``list`` is no more the name of the previous list, modified or not; it is only the **number** ``list[1] - list[0]`` . Hence you can't do ``list.pop(0)``. By the way it is ``pop(0)``, not ``pop[0]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify your code as follows:

```
transcriptionFile = 'calculus.txt'

with open(transcriptionFile, "r") as tFile:
        for line in tFile :
                li = line.split()
                if li: 
                        new = ((int(li[1]) - int(li[0]))/10000000. , li[2])     
                        print li,'  ',new
```

The condition `if li:` is here to eliminate possible void lines.

Important points:

- don't call a list with the name `list` because `list` is the name of built-in function of Python
- in Python,  `10/100` produces 0 ; you must put a dot to obtain the right result: `10./100` or `10/100.`
- do the calculus `list = list[1] - list[0]` before dividing by 10000000, it is more precise
- `with open(....) as handle:` is better to open the files

Personally, I would do

```
transcriptionFile = 'calculus.txt'

with open(transcriptionFile, "r") as tFile:
        gen = (line.split() for line in tFile if line.strip())
        li = [((int(t2)-int(t1))/10000000.,phon) for (t1,t2,phon) in gen]
        print '\n'.join(map(str,li))
```

Note that I used 10000000. to divide: if `1600000 - 1200000 = 400000` is in a unit which is 100 nanoseconds, then `400000 / 10000000` is 0.04 second

### Edit 1

```
transcriptionFile = 'calculus.txt'

with open(transcriptionFile, "r") as tFile:
        gen = (line.split() for line in tFile if line.strip())
        firstVals, lapTimes = [],[]
        for (t1,t2,phon) in gen:
                firstVals.append( (int(t1)/10000000.,phon) )
                lapTimes.append( (int(t2)-int(t1))/10000000.,phon) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the last one and it displays as ValueError : need more than 2 values to unpack in the second last line.

Comment: Also I tried the first one and it displays an error on the last print line as syntax error. I am so dumb I cant even figure out the answer when errors are displayed.

Comment: @Shivani Please, make a list of ``gen``, that is to say replace the parens with brackets: ``gen = [line.split() for line in tFile if line.strip()]`` then make ``print gen`` and see what are the values in **gen**. Normaly these values are lists like ``['3100000', '3400000', 'aa']``

Comment: @Shivani I copied/pasted the first code and executed it, no error is raised for me. Give the error message , please for this first code

Comment: @ eyquem: It works. Thanks you very much. You are a star. I also have to extract the first items of the list and change them into seconds. So I added i = [(int(t1))/10000000.) for (t1) in gen]. Is it correct? Does it make any sense?

Comment: @Shivani There is one parenthesis in excess in ``(int(t1))/10000000.)`` and you don't need more parens than ``int(t1)/10000000.`` - The part ``for (t1) in gen'' is wrong: (t1) means the object t1, you don't need the parenthesis , and **gen** as I defined produces triples, not alone numbers.

Comment: @ eyqueen: I am really sorry that was a syntax error. I have fixed it.

Comment: I added a line in the first code and now it works perfectly well. I got what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Shivani It depends what you want to obtain as results. Do you want the first item accompnying the other data, or in a separate list ? In the first case, you simply write ``new = (int(li[0])/10000000., (int(li[1]) - int(li[0]))/10000000. , li[2])`` in the first code and ``li = [(int(t1)/10000000.,(int(t2)-int(t1))/10000000.,phon) for (t1,t2,phon) in gen]`` in the second code

Comment: I actually need 2 lists with the first one with just first values in seconds and another one the difference between in seconds. I have got them. Used the first case.Thank you

Comment: @eyquem let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1874/discussion-between-shivani-and-eyquem)

Answer (score 5):

First, don't use `list` as a variable name. Every time you do that, a kitten dies.

Second, you should convert the strings you've extracted from your file to a number, preferably a [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) if you value the precision. Currently you're trying to divide a string.

Third, nanoseconds are billionths of a second, not millionths.

Fourth, it's `tFile.close()`, not `close.tfile`.

Fifth, use `for line in tfile:`. A file descriptor is already an iterator.

Sixth, use `with open(transcriptionfile, "r") as tfile:` and be done with having to close it.

Comment: Thank you. Its in the form of 100 nano seconds.

Comment: Please, think of the kittens!

Comment: @Shivani: `100000000` is 100 million. You're off by a factor `1000`. You need to divide by `100000000000.0`!

Comment: If I should not use list as variable then is it like for item in list do the following and so?

Comment: I dont understand about the kittens. What do you mean by that? I am really stupid and just a beginner.

Comment: `list` is the name of Python's built-in list constructor. If you use `list` as a variable name, you're overwriting that. Use `mylist` or something more descriptive. The kittens are a joke.

Comment: @ Tim: I realised that after posting the question that it should be close.tFile. I have changed it already. Thank you anyway for pointing my mistake.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. If I open a file in read mode is it not necessary to close it? Do I have to add the last line close.tFile?

Comment: @Shivani replace `tFile = open(transcriptionFile, "r")`
with `with open(transcriptionFile, "r") as tFile:`. The [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement will close the file for you.

Comment: You really should read a basic Python tutorial. If you do `tfile = open(...)` then you need to do `tfile.close()` (*not* `close.tfile`!!) when you're done. If you do `with open(...) as tfile:`, the file will be automatically closed for you when the `with` block is left.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker A billion is 1,000,000,000 (am I right ?). If 400000 was in nanosecond unity, it would be necessary to divide with 1,000,000,000. But a difference 1600000-1200000 (second line of the file) = 400000 means 400000 * 100 nanoseconds, if I understood well. So to obtain the value expressed in second unity, we must do 400000*100 / 1,000,000,000 that is to say 400000 / 1,000,000,0 . I think so. Did you add 2 zeros by mistake instead of eliminating 2 ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @eyquem: You're probably right, but then it should be 10.000.000, right?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker What should be 10.000.000 ? By the way, why do you use dots in this "number" ? I used the anglo-saxon notation in which commas are only typographic elements. In India they write big numbers grouping digits by two, apart the 3 last ones: 1,00,00,00,000 I believe. However I am not expert in the anglo-saxon notation.

Comment: @eyquem, sorry, that was European notation (dots as thousands separators, comma as decimal separator), and I had overlooked the final 0 in your 1,000,000,0 (although I must say that I've never seen 10 million written that way).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Aaaah, OK, I understand now. I have been stupid until now. First, when I used commas in the numbers, and I wrote **1,000,000,0**, it was to make clear the elimination of 2 zeros from **10,000,000,000** : I thought it would be evident that this was only to make it more readable and understandable, but that the real notation should be **10,000,000** .

Comment: @Tim Poietzcker  Secondly, I used commas, implying that I was respecting the fact that dots are used in english notation of numbers to divide digits of a number into 2 parts. I was so much in this mood of mind that I didn't imagine that you had written **10.000.000** in the european manner. The best of it is that I AM european ! I'm sorry for my clumsiness.

Answer (score 1):

`line.split()` returns a list of strings. Try `list[0] = float(list[0]) / 100000000`.

This converts each string to a number which supports division before you do your calculations.

Comment: Not an array, a list of strings. In Python, arrays are this : (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array)

Answer (score 0):

You do not convert the strings to numerical values. In order to conduct mathematical operations on your data, you have to convert the either to `int` or `float` objects:

```
valueA = int(list[0]) / 100000000
valueB = int(list[1]) / 100000000
```

Comment: Don't use `int` - all results would be 0.